# PHP array intersection - finding common subsets

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, tree, intersection

I have data stored in mongodb collection - pages. Each page has following attributes:

```
    title - string 
    id - number
    contents - it is an object with 3 attribute
       contents.topic  - string
       contents.parentTopic - number
       contents.text - string
```

I have roughly 500 pages stored in DB and performance isn't a very big consideration for me.

I need to find common contents across all pages. If I do following:

```
    $pages = $db->selectCollection("pages");       
    $cursor = $pages->find(array());
    $data = array();

    foreach ( $cursor as $page ){
        array_push($data,$page);
    }
    $intersect = call_user_func_array('array_intersect_assoc',$data);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($intersect);
```

Like this I can get common contents across all pages which is working fine. This is true as long as there is at least one common 'content' across all pages.

But I need to find common sub-sets across all pages. For example, find the content that is common in pages 1-50, may be another subset that is common in pages 45,59,79,123,... another might be common in pages 450 - 459

Any better solution of finding such common sub-sets? Will it require creating trees?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose of such similarity check? I imagine that resources required will grow exponentially when pages count will get bigger.

Comment: Thats right but the pages count isn't expected to grow and will pretty much remain around 500.

Answer (score 0):

It all really depends on "which" attributes you deem as "duplicated" or at least "common to a set".

You can do

```
$pages->aggregate(
  array(
    '$group' => array(
      '_id' => '$content',
      'pages' => array( '$push' => '$id' ),
      'count' => array( '$sum' => 1 )
    )
  )
);
```

Which is a lot more efficient that the client code you are using.

Or you can even do

```
$pages->aggregate(
  array(
    array( 
      '$project' => array(
        'title' => 1,
        'id' => 1,
        'contents' => 1,
        'types' => array( '$literal' => array( 'topic', 'parentTopic', 'text' ) )
      )
    ),
    array( '$unwind' => '$types' ),
      array(
        '$group' => array(
          '_id' => array( 
            'type' => '$types',
            'content' => array(
              '$cond' => array(
                array( '$eq' => array( '$types', 'topic' ) ),
                '$content.topic',
                array(
                  '$cond' =>  array(
                    array( '$eq' => array( '$types', 'parentTopic' ) ),
                    '$content.parentTopic',
                    '$content.text'
                  )
                )
              )
            )
          ),
          'pages' => array( '$push' => '$id' ),
          'count' => array( '$sum' => 1 )
        )
      )
    )
  )
);
```

Which groups by each sub-key.

All "grouping" is a form of 'set building'. But it's really not that clear what you are asking for here. Just trying to show something more efficient that what you seem to be doing.

Comment: That's right but it I have 500 pages and each page has nearly 400-500 content blocks. I need to find content blocks which are common across these pages. It isn't necessary that a content block exist in all pages, so I need to find smaller subsets. I will give a try to group by.